# How do I type accented characters in MacOS?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard

How do I type an accented letter, or an umlaut, etc?

Comment: Which keyboard, which language, which OS Version?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type accented characters like ü and ö in macOS?](https://superuser.com/questions/1745263/how-do-i-type-accented-characters-like-%c3%bc-and-%c3%b6-in-macos)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you go to the International pane of System Preferences and turn on the Input menu (I’m not at my Mac now, so I can’t give you exact details), there will also be an option to show the Keyboard Viewer in the Input menu. Once you’ve done that, you should see a little flag icon in your menubar, from which you can turn on the Keyboard Viewer.

Once the keyboard viewer is up, you can hold down option and/or shift to see what the different option combos will result in. It also has some kind of visual indicator (I think the key cap is outlined) for the “dead keys”, i.e. accents that you follow with the letter that goes below them.

Answer (score 9):

A couple examples

<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> then <kbd>e</kbd> will show é
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> then <kbd>u</kbd> will show ü
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> then <kbd>i</kbd> will show î
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> then <kbd>a</kbd> will show à
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> then <kbd>n</kbd> will show ñ
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will show ç
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> will show ø
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will show ¡
<kbd>Opt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> will show ¿

Answer (score 3):

- Hold option and hit e then type your
  letter for an accented letter.
- Hold option and hit u then type your
  letter for a letter with an umlaut.

I think there are others but I'm too lazy to look them up.

Comment: option c, option n, option grave, option i

Comment: I get a Euro sign on typing option+e. And if I got an accented letter, which accent would it have? On the other hand: It doesn’t hurt (and it’s quite fun if you’re bored) trying out all combinations, if you really want to know.

Comment: More details: http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/type_european.html

Comment: @DougHarris The link is broken.

Comment: Link from archive.org: http://web.archive.org/web/20100210111634/http://www.apple.com/pro/tips/type_european.html

Answer (score 2):

In OSX Lion and beyond, you can also type accented letters by pressing and holding the base character that you'd like to accent and then choosing your preferred accented variant from the resulting pop-up list.

Answer (score 0):

Old question with decent answers. All of the answers here touch on the magic use of the <kbd>Option</kbd> plus another key and then just pressing yet another key.

But I find this guide for “[Using Symbols and Diacritical Marks on macOS](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/diacritics.html)” from Reed College to be pretty good overall reference:

> | Diacritical Name | Appearance | Key Command |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Acute | á, é, í | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Grave | è, à, ù | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Tilde | ñ Ñ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Circumflex | ê Ê | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Umlaut | ä Ä ö Ö ü Ü | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Cedilla | ç Ç | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> |
> | Inverted Question Mark | ¿ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> |
> | Inverted Exclamation Mark | ¡ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> |
> | Esszet | ß | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> |
> | Pound | £ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> |
> | Cents | ¢ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> |
> | Pilcrow (paragraph) | ¶ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> |
> | Section | § | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> |
> | Degree | º | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> |
> | Copyright | © | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> |
> | Delta | ∆ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> |
> | Bullet | • | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> |