# Smartphone-style keyboard on Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout

I very much like the way Smartphone keyboards work. Pressing, a tangent for example, 'A' gives me the different variations/alternatives to 'A':

[image]

Is there something very similar to use on a Windows (8) desktop computer? That is just pressing a specific key on my physical keyboard would make something similar popup?

I will have great use of something like that especially when using letters from different languages for example the german 'ß' or french 'Œ' and 'Æ'.

Comment: The MIT-licensed SymWin answer in [this](http://superuser.com/questions/110605/how-do-i-type-accented-characters-in-windows) question use CapsLock to trigger displaying the different accents, the developer mentioned some problem with Metro apps. Meanwhile there's a [dirt cheap freemium app](http://www.holdkey.eu/) that exactly mimic smartphone style

Comment: Some of the answers at http://superuser.com/questions/110605/how-do-i-type-accented-characters-in-windows show scripts to achieve this.

Comment: today in 2024, the suggestion right below of PowerToys by @HonzaZidek is a great way to have what most people want -- totally free Microsoft app with zero scripting

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Microsoft PowerToys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/install). It should be safe as it comes directly from Microsoft.
2. Open the program.
3. Activate "Quick Accent" - see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/powertoys/quick-accent).
4. Hold any letter key + an activation key (e.g. <kbd>→</kbd>). Keep holding the key. A selection toolbar appears:

[image]

Comment: wow . . . how have I never heard of PowerToys before . . . love it !!!  
This is a great solution for working in your native keyboard setup and still using diacritics for other languages - probably what most people would want to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 8 (or 10) allows you to add the touch keyboard button to the taskbar. Simply right-click the taskbar and select "Show touch keyboard button". You can then control the keyboard with the mouse, using the same long press as you described for a phone keyboard. This keyboard allows access to Œ through O and Æ through A. It also has additional keyboards of emoji, etc.

Comment: Thank you. That might do it but it would take up space on the screen though. If possible I would prefer using my physical keyboard (though selecting the alternative character might need using the mouse depending upon how it's implemented).

Comment: Actually... the touch keyboard was better than I first thought. I first though you meant the old-style virtual keyboard that is worse.

I am a little bit annoyed by the size of the keys though, if they could be shrinked then I would be maximally happy.

Comment: The bottom right corner button (keyboard options) will allow you to select a split keyboard which will be smaller. (On Windows 8 it will be shorter, but on Windows 10 you will actually get two separate keyboard windows)