# Can I type accented characters (é, ř, ...) in Windows by holding a key (like on Android)?

Tags: windows, keyboard

Is there a way to set up Microsoft Windows so you can enter accented characters (with diacritics, such as `é`, `ř`, ...) by holding a key and then selecting the variant you like? I mean a similar way like on tablets and mobile phones.

E.g. you hold the key **`E`** and instead of auto-repeating the same character the system would offer you a small menu on the position of the cursor offering **`É`**, **`È`**, **`Ê`** etc.

Note: I *am* aware of other ways to enter accented characters. This question is *purely* about this particular typing method and if it is possible to set up on Microsoft Windows. Maybe using a 3rd party software?

EDIT:

I solved the problem with Microsoft Power Toys / Quick Accent, see my answer https://superuser.com/a/1751506/282786

Comment: Which version of windows do you mean?

Comment: Any version form 8.1 up, I can easily upgrade to 10.

Comment: I think you can do this in Microsoft Word, however that's a software only thing and won't work anywhere else.

Comment: I solved the problem with Microsoft Power Toys / Quick Accent, see my answer https://superuser.com/a/1751506/282786