# How to enter accented characters like "ü" and "ö" in Windows?

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, special-characters

In Windows, I can't type characters like ü and ö. How do I enter these characters on Windows?

Comment: Nitpick: These are *characters*, not *words*, and the operating system is called "Windows".

Comment: Sorry, but I am voting to close this since the original poster has provided no details and has consistently commented on 4 of the 5 answers — oddly including the one they checked off as the answer — with “This answer didn't help me.” Without details and with multiple clear answers, why is that the response?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I disagree. Commenys are not relevant. The question has received a correct answer upvoted by 7 persons. It has several good answers which can help others. Closing it would be counterproductive.

Comment: @1NN Fair enough. But the question is confusing for many. I almost feel for the original poster: In 2022 many people using OSes like macOS don’t have to jump through hoops to add accents. So that said, [this new answer](https://superuser.com/a/1744198/167207) seems to be the most viable answer here since it doesn’t require memorizing decimal codes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I type accented characters in windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/110605/how-do-i-type-accented-characters-in-windows)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The easiest method is, to add a keyboard language.

If you go to Settings -> Time and language -> Language you can add a language.

Add English (United States International) and switch to it. You can now use the right alt (now known as alt gr) to type special keys, such as altgr+w = å,  alt-gr + shift + ; for ° or you can type "o to type ö and "u as ü, or ~n as ñ, 'e as é, `e as è, 'c as ç ^i as î. To type the ", you type " followed by pressing space, or alternatively switch back to your other keyboard language.

Comment: @MyCar The answer alone won't jump off the page and configure Windows for you - it's up to you to take the steps described in the answer.  If you want additional help you must communicate to us what difficulties you had in attempting to implement this answer and how the results differed from what you expected or would have liked it to have been.

Comment: @MyCar If this answer didn't help you why did you check it off as the answer? Only upvote and check off answers that help you. No disrespect to  LPChip.

Comment: This is upvoted a lot, so I guess this is working in some version of windows. In the version of Windows 10 I am using you need to add "English (United States)" and then click on "English(United States) -> Options -> Keyboard" and choose "English (USA, International)" there.

Answer (score 8):

A few options.

1. Open up the character map using Start > Run > `charmap`, find the character in the table and copy it to the clipboard
2. Find the [Decimal code](https://www.ascii-code.com/), and use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + the appropriate number

e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0176</kbd> results in the ° symbol.

For the 2 symbols you mention, the keyboard codes are below:

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0246</kbd> results in ö

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>0252</kbd> results in ü

Comment: These are not ASCII codes. ASCII is a 7-bit character encoding, and only has 128 characters.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do that with the numpad.

Hold down alt key and type in the following for:

- **ö**: <kbd>alt</kbd>+148
- **Ö**: <kbd>alt</kbd>+0214
- **ü**: <kbd>alt</kbd>+0252
- **Ü**: <kbd>alt</kbd>+0220

After typing in the number let off alt and you'll get your character.
More key combinations here:
https://www.unlockyourhistory.com/post/%C3%A4-%C3%AB-%C3%AF-%C3%B6-%C3%BC-umlaut-on-the-keyboard

Comment: @MyCar all of the answers here work. Although the answers that switch the keyboard layout work more reliably because alt codes like this depend on the locale. So the problem is actually on your side and you didn't even stated clearly. For example did you use the **numpad keys** correctly? The real solution is to install a keyboard layout for your target language, for example installer German keyboard if you want to type German

Answer (score 4):

As of Windows 11, the native `notepad.exe` program now supports shortcuts for accented characters.

As I'd personally rather not switch my keyboard for the sake of some characters I don't often use, I find the quickest and most convenient method (excluding AHK or Alt-code entry) is to simply call`notepad.exe` via `run` (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, type `notepad`, <kbd>Enter</kbd>) and type the desired accent letter (refer to Microsoft's [support page on inserting international characters](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keyboard-shortcuts-in-word-95ef89dd-7142-4b50-afb2-f762f663ceb2#bkmk_intlcharwin)), use `FIND TEXT` for "accent" on that page; I'll also include a screenshot of the relevant table for retention).

I would then copy and paste from there:

| To insert this | Press |
| --- | --- |
| à, è, ì, ò, ù, À, È, Ì, Ò, Ù | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Grave accent (`), the letter |
| á, é, í, ó, ú, ý Á, É, Í, Ó, Ú, Ý | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Single quotation mark ('), the letter |
| â, ê, î, ô, û, Â, Ê, Î, Ô, Û | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Caret (^), the letter |
| ã, ñ, õ, Ã, Ñ, Õ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Tilde (~), the letter |
| ä, ë, ï, ö, ü, ÿ, Ä, Ë, Ï, Ö, Ü, Ÿ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Colon (:), the letter |
| å, Å | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+At sign (@), a or A |
| æ, Æ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Ampersand (&), a or A |
| œ, Œ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Ampersand (&), o or O |
| ç, Ç | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Comma (,), c or C |
| ð, Ð | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Single quotation mark ('), d or D |
| ø, Ø | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Forward slash (/), o or O |
| ¿ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Question mark (?) |
| ¡ | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Exclamation point (!) |
| ß | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+Ampersand (&), s |

Answer (score 1):

Look for the <kbd>"</kbd> (two dots) symbol on your keyboard (Which is DISTINCT from the double quote <kbd>"</kbd>). On some keyboards you need to use <kbd>AltGr</kbd>. Press first that key, and then <kbd>o</kbd>, <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>u</kbd> or whatever. The exact position on your keyboard will vary according to your language.

For example, on a US-English keyboard, you'll find the character to the left of the <kbd>Return</kbd> key, on the same key as the double quote, and you need to press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>AltGr</kbd> together with the corresponding key (see image - the key has a magenta frame):

[image]

Comment: This will only work if your keyboardlayout supports it. See my answer. On a keyboard layout with only United States, this will not work.

Comment: I wish to remove my downvote now but can't until the answer is edited. :(

Comment: @RossPresser I've loaned you an upvote until it is edited ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of course, the easiest way is to own a German keyboard.

Otherwise, you can simply call up a page on which these umlauts appear (e.g. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut) and copy them from there if it is not often necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Really, most of the previous answers are excessively complicated, as they depend on arbitrary codes that no one could be expected to know. It's time-consuming and difficult to find any specific character in the Windows Character Map.

I think it was in Windows 10 that the so-called "emoji picker" was introduced. Typing [Windows Key] + [Period] brings it up, and has numerous pages and tabs from which one can select (simply by clicking on) all manner of symbols and non-English characters. And of course emojis.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-keyboard-tips-and-tricks-588e0b72-0fff-6d3f-aeee-6e5116097942

Answer (score 0):

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/keyboard-shortcuts-for-international-characters-108fa0c1-fb8e-4aae-9db1-d60407d13c35

To type a lowercase character by using a key combination that includes the SHIFT key, hold down the CTRL+SHIFT+symbol keys simultaneously, and then release them before you type the letter.

ä, ë, ï, ö, ü, ÿ,
Ä, Ë, Ï, Ö, Ü, Ÿ

CTRL+SHIFT+: (COLON), the letter

Comment: Hello, that looks like instructions for Outlook, which doesn't reall answer the question.