# How do I type accented characters like ü and ö in macOS?

Tags: macos, characters

In macOS, I can't type characters like ü and ö. How to enter these characters in macOS?

Appreciate if someone can suggest me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While the long click works, specifically for the characters `ü` and `ö` in macOS you can click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> for [umlaut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaeresis_(diacritic)), then type the key you want to have an umlaut. This was done on a macOS U.S. English keyboard.

- For `ä`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>A</kbd>.
- For `ë`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>E</kbd>.
- For `ï`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>I</kbd>.
- For `ö`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>O</kbd>.
- For `ü`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>U</kbd>.
- For `ÿ`, click <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> and then click <kbd>Y</kbd>.

This works for uppercase as well as lowercase characters and there are other similar items such as:

- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> for an [acute accent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) like `é`.
- <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> for a [circumflex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumflex) like `î`.

This guide for “[Using Symbols and Diacritical Marks on macOS](https://www.reed.edu/cis/help/diacritics.html)” from Reed College seems like a pretty good reference:

> | Diacritical Name | Appearance | Key Command |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | Acute | á, é, í | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Grave | è, à, ù | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Tilde | ñ Ñ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Circumflex | ê Ê | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>i</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Umlaut | ä Ä ö Ö ü Ü | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>, then the letter you wish to accent. |
> | Cedilla | ç Ç | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> or <kbd>C</kbd> |
> | Inverted Question Mark | ¿ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>?</kbd> |
> | Inverted Exclamation Mark | ¡ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> |
> | Esszet | ß | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> |
> | Pound | £ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> |
> | Cents | ¢ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> |
> | Pilcrow (paragraph) | ¶ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>7</kbd> |
> | Section | § | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd> |
> | Degree | º | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd> |
> | Copyright | © | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>g</kbd> |
> | Delta | ∆ | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>j</kbd> |
> | Bullet | • | <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>8</kbd> |

Comment: Great answer! +1

Comment: Can you take a look at this question: https://superuser.com/questions/1745269/how-to-enter-special-characters-like-%E2%88%9E-%CB%9A-in-macos

Comment: @MyCar I looked at it. Looks fine. Nothing new to add.

Comment: I wish there were more examples of special characters, not just ∞ and º

Comment: I said "like ∞, ˚" in the title

Comment: @MyCar Fair enough. Just [posted an answer](https://superuser.com/a/1745275/167207) that explains how you can discover this stuff on your own.

Answer (score 2):

Just long press <kbd>u</kbd> on the keyboard and it will display something like this:

[image]

Then, press <kbd>2</kbd>(mine is 2, maybe yours is 1, 3, etc.) on the keyboard and ü will appear.

To enter ö, just do the same thing: long press <kbd>o</kbd> on your keyboard, then press <kbd>2</kbd>(mine is 2, maybe yours is 1, 3, etc.).